# Kibana 3 - Extract the query automatically then use it in a watcher

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to create a watcher based on a Kibana 3 dashboard. Meaning I want the watcher to run the same query as the dashboard. Is there any automated way (using some sort of api) to copy the query from kibana?

In my research i found a manual way of doing so, by clicking on the "Inspect" button in the dashboard documents visualization.

A picture of the Inspect button : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofqcn.png

Any ideas?